# res_model not valid openErp 6.1

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-6

Having this py file:
from osv import osv, fields

```
class my_class(osv.osv_memory):
 _name = 'my.class'
  _columns = {
   'column1': fields.integer('Column1:'),
   'column2': fields.integer('Column2:'),
 } 
my_class()
```

a viue like:

```
  <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_my_class">
    <field name="name">my.class.form</field>
    <field name="model">my.class</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
     <field name="Column1"/>
     <field name="Column2"/>
    </field>
  </record>
```

and an action view inside xml with this format:

```
  <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_my_action'">
    <field name="name">Stuff,,,</field>
    <field name="res_model">my.class</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_my_class"/>
    <field name="target">new</field>
  </record>
```

It appears this errror:

Validate Error
An error has occurred while the field (s) res_model, src_model validated: Invalid model name in the action definition.

Why?

PD: its a wizard part of my own module.

Comment: Can you please share code of other files like __init__.py ?

Comment: main init imports main addon file, wizard init imports its correct file, what else you need?

Answer (score 0):

> main init imports main addon file, wizard init imports its correct
> file, what else you need? – Mark Dec 12 '15 at 11:30

4 years later... do you check your main `__init__.py` for wizard imports?
anyway, take it as a state of mind :)  It has taken me years too...